# How do I set a custom sorter on vaadin tables?

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to make my tables ignore letter case when sorting, so I found [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/339736) link, but I can't figure out where I can actually make the table use the new ItemSorter.

Comment: your table is in some kind of Container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the ItemSorter to the *container* used by the table; two container types expose #setItemSorter - IndexedContainer and AbstractBeanContainer. The default container for a Vaadin table is an IndexedContainer.

The following snippet should add an ItemSorter to a table.

```
Container container = table.getContainerDataSource();      
  if (container instanceof IndexedContainer) {
    ((IndexedContainer) container).setItemSorter(itemSorter);
  } else if (container instanceof AbstractBeanContainer){
    ((AbstractBeanContainer) container).setItemSorter(itemSorter);
  }
```